# How to deploy a FastAPI endpoint using pythonanywhere?

Tags: fastapi, pythonanywhere

I have been trying to deploy EasyOCR (it's fine if it works on CPU) with FastAPI endpoints such that anyone can use it via https POST request. It runs fine on my local host but when I have been facing challenges in deploying it using pythonanywhere. I added the  additional requirements like pip install easyocr, pip install python-multipart==0.0.5.

The following is my code-

```
import io
import logging
import re

from fastapi import FastAPI, APIRouter, Request, File, UploadFile
from fastapi.responses import FileResponse, StreamingResponse
import easyocr

import PIL
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import numpy

app = FastAPI()
router = APIRouter()
ocr = easyocr.Reader(["en"])
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)
logger = logging.getLogger("ocr")


@app.get("/")
async def root():
    return {"message": "Hello World"}


@app.post("/ocr")
async def do_ocr(request: Request, file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    if file is not None:
        imgFile = numpy.array(PIL.Image.open(file.file).convert("RGB"))
        res = ocr.readtext(imgFile)

        # return array of strings
        return [item[1] for item in res]

    return {"error": "missing file"}


app.include_router(router)
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import uvicorn

    uvicorn.run(app)
```

I am getting the error in the logs-

```
During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/somyatomar15/main.py", line 82, in <module>
    uvicorn.run(app)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/main.py", line 463, in run
    server.run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 60, in run
    return asyncio.run(self.serve(sockets=sockets))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 633, in run_until_complete
    self.run_forever()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 600, in run_forever
    self._run_once()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 1896, in _run_once
    handle._run()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/asyncio/events.py", line 80, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback, *self._args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 77, in serve
    await self.startup(sockets=sockets)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/uvicorn/server.py", line 158, in startup
    sys.exit(1)
SystemExit: 1
```

Comment: ASGI web apps are not currently supported on PythonAnywhere, so FastAPI would not work.